# Java - Thread State Exception

Tags: java, multithreading

I got the following error when I try to start again my thread.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
     at java.lang.Thread.start(Unknown Source)
     at com.jrat.server.Server.run(Server.java:159)
```

Here is the line:

```
if (!t.isAlive()) t.start();
```

The code can be executed many times as it is in a loop (socket handler).
As far as I know, this error means that it can't start a new Thread because it is already running. What's weird is I have a isAlive before.

Any idea why it is like that?

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot use this voodoo to bring dead threads back to life. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Please describe your task in details. What has happened when you try to restart the thread? When the thread is running, does it handle a single such event or can process them in a loop? If in a loop, where the events are stored (which are not handled yet)? Does the thread exits when all available events are handled?

Comment: Yes - why can't you just loop in the thread or submit your thread method to a threadpool.  Continually creating, starting, running terminating and destroying threads, almost like they are normal functions, is just.. well, it's just wrong in 99.9% of cases.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to execute a system command. I send data through a socket to my server and it executes the command. The command is in the thread. As I can specify which command I want to execute, I have to restart the thread with the given command. I also need to stop the thread if I want to interrupt the execution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> As far as I know, this error means that it can't start a new Thread because it is already running.

No, it means you can't start a thread which has already been started.

You can't *restart* a thread, which is what you're trying to do. From [the documentation for `start()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29):

> Throws: IllegalThreadStateException - if the thread was already started.

You should probably be using an `ExecutorService` instead, at a guess - but it's not really clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can't call start on a Thread that has been started previously. Even if the thread run method has terminated.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is that if your thread is not alive, start it. But it is conceptually wrong.

You can't call the start method even if your thread is not alive. If you have started it once, you can't start it again even after it has completed its execution.

If what you are intending to do is to re-run a task, then you can try ExecutorService.

Answer (score 1):

Vodemki, creating a new thread every time you have a task is expensive. You should use a thread pool. Basically what it does is that you have a pool of n threads and you submit tasks to it. If some thread is free, it will perform your task. If some thread is done with its task, it goes back to the pool waiting for some other task.

Try using ExecutorService for pooling threads.

Answer (score 0):

I found the easiest way:

Every time I need to start a new Thread, I create a new one:

```
Thread t = new Thread()
{
    public void run()
    {
        // Do your deal here
    }
};
t.start();
```